# Crystal Report (Load Report Failed) Error in Client machine

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, desktop-application

Crystal report is loading on my PC but when I deploy my desktop app on client PC it gives this error

> Load Report Failed

I have tried multiple ways changed path of reports , installed crystal report runtime same version as in my pc on client pc but didn't solve this error.
Please help to solve this. **Thanks**

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/07/183d21e5-597c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html